# F# tuple, System.Tuple and collection - Type constraint mismatch?

Tags: f#

The last two lines in the following code got the compiler error?

```
open System

let s = new System.Collections.Generic.Stack<Tuple<int, int>>()
s.Push( 1, 2) // The type ''a * 'b' is not compatible with the type 'Tuple<int,int>'
s.Push(Tuple.Create(1, 2))
```

The error message of the `s.Push(Tuple.Create(1, 2))`

```
Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    ''a * 'b'    
is not compatible with type
    'Tuple'
The type ''a * 'b' is not compatible with the type 'Tuple'
type Tuple =
  static member Create : item1:'T1 -> Tuple + 7 overloads
Full name: System.Tuple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though F# tuples are represented with `System.Tuple` in compiled form, they are not considered an "alias" for it from the logical language standpoint.

`int * int` is not the same as `System.Tuple<int, int>` as far as F# compiler is concerned.

Just use the F# tuple syntax for the `Stack` generic argument, and it will work:

```
let s = new System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int * int>()
s.Push( 1, 2)
```

Comment: What the strangest thing is `let t = Tuple.Create(1,2)` got the type of `int*int` for `t` instead of `Tuple<int, int>`.

Comment: This is peculiar indeed. I have reported it as an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3016

Comment: Don closed the issue. However, I think the F# compiler should at least give some explanations - so people will not be confused.

Comment: Feel free to comment on the issue.